# Liferay: getting all available site languages

Tags: java, localization, liferay

As you know, in Liferay you can setup (portal-)languages which are available to sites.
In a site's controlpanel you can choose which of these languages should be available to a user of that site.

So far I have only found `languageUtil.getAvailableLocales()`, which returns a list of the available portal locales not the sites' locales.

Is there a way to get site languages?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use API method as below

`public static Locale[] com.liferay.portal.kernel.language.LanguageUtil.getAvailableLocales(long  groupId)`

Here groupId would be groupId of Site/Group, for which you want to get locales.

This method will return array of Locale.

Comment: Please dont be narrow with the contain. add better explanation.

Comment: to get the group id you just need to do themeDisplay.getScopeGroupId()